# Не создается окно в eclipse

Tags: java, swing, eclipse

Когда пытаюсь создать окно просто через некоторое время в консоли появляется надпись terminated и все. Мне сказали нужно использовать SwingUtilities, но это не помогло. На других компьютерах когда делал все получалось. Пример окна:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            () -> new Main()
        );
}
Main(){
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(
            JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE
        );
        this.setPreferredSize(
            new Dimension(1280, 1024)
        );
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

значит какая-то локальная ошибка.всё работает.может что-то в  Установке и настройке Eclipse.Переставлять Eclipse.попробуйте Debug.